# Covering space and computing $p_\ast(\pi_1(E,e_0))$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $X=S^1\vee S^2\vee S^2.$ I want to find an example of a 3-fold covering space $p:E\rightarrow X$ of $X$, and compute $p_\ast:\pi_1(E, e_0)\rightarrow\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and $p_\ast(\pi_1(E, e_0))$.

I know that $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^2\vee S^2)=\pi_1(S^1)\ast\pi_1(S^2)\ast\pi_1(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$.
So there is only one generator, say it is $a$. Then is $<a>$ a covering space of $S^1\vee S^2\vee S^2$? But it is not 3-fold. It is 1-fold. And after finding an example of a covering space how can I compute $p_\ast$ and $p_\ast(\pi_1(E, e_0))$? Any help is greatly appreciate.

[image]

Edit: I am also interested in: finding all three fold coverings of $X$ and distinguishing universal covering among them.

Comment: Consider three distinct points on a circle and add two $\Bbb S^2$ at each of these points tangentially. This is a three-fold cover. Now, induced map of $n$-fold **path-connected** cover has an image with index-$n$.

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta Thanks a lot. You've been answering my questions today, and I really appreciate that.  I added picture. I still don't understanding computing part. Could you elaborate? Do we have explicit formula for $p_\ast$? How can we find it?

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta Thanks! I got that part. Do you know how can I come up with whole list of 3-fold covering?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z$ has exactly one subgroup with index-$3$. So, for any other $3$-fold covering $\widetilde p:(\widetilde E,\widetilde e_0)\to (X,x_0)$ we have a homeomorphism $h:(\widetilde E,\widetilde e_0)\to (E,e_0)$ such that $ph=\widetilde p$.

Comment: **Universal Cover:** At integer point of $\Bbb R$ add two $\Bbb S^2$ tangentially.

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta But isn't the fundamental group of the space (at integer point of $\mathbb{R}$ add two $\mathbb{S}^2$) a $\mathbb{Z}$? Therefore it is not a universal cover?